# SharePoint 2013 Global Navigations links disappear when deploying SitePages from Visual Studio

Tags: 2013, navigation, global-navigation, sitepages

When I deploy a Visual Studio 2012 project with a SharePoint Module containing several Site Pages, the SharePoint 2013 website loses the configured navigation nodes for those Site Pages in the Global Navigation.

My questions are: why do they disappear and how can I prevent it?

The steps I take are:

1. I configure the navigation bar (global navigation) from `_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx`
2. The navigation looks how I want it.
3. I deploy Site Pages from Visual Studio

[image]

4. Navigation nodes are gone from global navigation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the answer to my own question:

When you open up the content database in SQL Server Management studio (most commonly **WSS_Content**), and then open up the **NavNodes** table in edit modus (right click: "Edit Top 200 Rows"), you should change the following 2 columns from the relevant nodes:

- **ElementType** should be "1" indstead of "0"
- **DocId** should be "NULL"

When you deploy Site Pages again, you will notice the navigation for the deployed pages won't disappear. (If they still disappear, try *iisreset* in command prompt).